# regular expression for 4 number, a comma and 4 numbers

Tags: c#, regex

Using a regular expression, I would like to match the following string:

```
4232,2232
```

I have tried

```
^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)$
```

However, it doesn't work as expected. I want to cater for 4 numbers, a comma and 4 numbers.

Comment: `^\d{4},\d{4}$` should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand you correctly the RegEx you are looking for is basically:

```
(\d{4},\d{4})
```

This matches your provided expression as one group.
As an alternative you could write:

```
([0-9]{4},[0-9]{4})
```

which has the same result.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following:

```
\d{4},\d{4}    //or ^\d{4},\d{4}$ with anchors for start and end of string
```

Explanation:

- `\d{4}` match digits exactly 4 times (`\d` is shorthand notation for `[0-9]`)
- `,\d{4}` followed by comma and exactly 4 digits again

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you can use `Regex.IsMatch` with the `\b\d{4},\d{4}\b` regex:

```
var found_value1 = Regex.IsMatch("4232,2232", @"\b\d{4},\d{4}\b");
var found_value2 = Regex.IsMatch("12345,2232", @"\b\d{4},\d{4}\b");
```

`\b` makes sure we match whole number.

Output:

```
true
false
```